# Unknown egress traffic on brand new GCE instance

Tags: instance, google-compute-engine, traffic

I'm new to Google Compute Engine and I just setup a new instance that will eventually become a web server.  All the firewall rules were left at default when the instance was created, which leaves open a few ports (RDP, SSH, etc) for administration.  No software was installed or DNS records pointing to the server were created and I left the instance running.

After a couple weeks, I looked at the billing and there were over 300 mebibytes of data billed due to egress traffic to China and America.  I'm wondering if this is a normal.

Is there any particular reason hundreds of megs of traffic went out on a brand new, firewalled instance?  Does the Google cloud service offer some kind of network analysis tool to breakdown traffic by type/destination?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Stackdriver monitoring to see the history of your ingress and egress traffic of your VM instances. However to get more information of traffic (like IPs, packets, requests, etc..) you will need to install a third party monitoring tool or to use a packet capturing tool (Wireshark, tcpdump,...) to analyze your traffics.